# Footmark closer to text

Tags: stacking-symbols

[image]

I want the footmark to be closer to the inequality sign.

```
\stackrel{\footnotemark[1]}{\leq}
\footnotetext[1]{Test}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you sure your readers will understand that the asterisk is a footnote marker and not a symbol part of the formula?

Comment: Just use ` \stackrel{\ast}{\leq}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

With `stackengine`, one can specify the gap size, in this case chosen as -3pt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
$A\mathrel{\stackon[-3pt]{\leq}{\footnotemark[1]}} B$
\footnotetext[1]{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]